# OS Programming with SystemV IPC. I get an error when I delete the semaphores

Tags: c, operating-system, ipc, semaphore, shared-memory

this is the producer.c file

```
/* gcc -D_REENTRANT main.c -Ipthread -pthread -o main *
 * gcc -D_REENTRANT main.c -o main -Ipthread -pthread */ 


#include <stdbool.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "Semaphores.h"


#define N 1024


typedef struct {
    bool end;
    float array[N];
    unsigned long index;
} SharedMemory;


#define SHM_SIZE sizeof(SharedMemory)


#define SEM_KEY (key_t) 1234
#define SHM_KEY (key_t) 5678

#define READ_SEM 0
#define WRITE_SEM 1


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    srand((unsigned) time(NULL));
    int shm_id, sem_id;
    void *mem_addr;
    SharedMemory *mem;
    int n_iterations, i;

    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("Usage: main <n_iterations> where n_iterations > 0");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    n_iterations = atoi(argv[1]);

    if (n_iterations <= 0) {
        printf("Error: n_iterations must be > 0");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Creating the semaphores array (2 semaphores: read and write) */
    sem_id = semget(SEM_KEY, 2, IPC_CREAT | 0666);

    if (sem_id == -1) {
        /* Show the error and exit */
        perror("Error creating the semaphore");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Creating the shared memory */
    shm_id = shmget(SHM_KEY, SHM_SIZE, IPC_CREAT | 0666);

    if (shm_id == -1) {
        /* Show the error and exit */
        perror("Error creating the shared memory");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Initializing the semaphores: * 
     * READ_SEM is set to 0 (data   *
     * needs to be written before   *
     * it's read) and so WRITE_SEM  *
     * is set to 1. Using SEM_SET() */

    if (SEM_SET(sem_id, READ_SEM, 0) == -1) {
        /* Show the error and exit() */
        perror("Error setting READ_SEM to 0");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (SEM_SET(sem_id, WRITE_SEM, 1) == -1) {
        /* Show the error and exit() */
        perror("Error setting WRITE_SEM to 1");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Attaching the process to shared memory */

    mem_addr = shmat(shm_id, (void *) 0, 0);

    if (mem_addr == (void *) -1) {
        /* Show error and exit() */
        perror("Error attaching memory");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("Memory set to address %X\n", (unsigned) mem_addr);

    mem = (SharedMemory *) mem_addr;

    mem->end = false;

    /* Now the process can start writing to the memory */

    while (mem->end == false) {
        for (i = 0; i < n_iterations; i++) {
            if (SEM_P(sem_id, WRITE_SEM) == -1) {
                perror("Error");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            mem->index = (unsigned long) rand() % N;
            int hold = rand() % 100;
            mem->array[mem->index] = (float) hold / (rand() % 10 + 1);
            if (SEM_V(sem_id, READ_SEM) == -1) {
                perror("Error");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }

        if (SEM_P(sem_id, WRITE_SEM) == -1) {
            perror("Error");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        mem->end = true;

        if (SEM_V(sem_id, READ_SEM) == -1) {
            perror("Error");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    /* Detatching memory and destroying it */
    if (shmdt(mem_addr) == -1) {
        perror("Error detatching memory");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (shmctl(shm_id, IPC_RMID, 0) == -1) {
        perror("Error erasing memory");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Destroying semaphores */
    SEM_DEL(sem_id, WRITE_SEM);
    SEM_DEL(sem_id, READ_SEM);

    printf("Finished.\n");

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

And this is the consumer.c one

```
/* gcc -D_REENTRANT main.c -Ipthread -pthread -o main *
 * gcc -D_REENTRANT main.c -o main -Ipthread -pthread */ 


#include <stdbool.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "Semaphores.h"


#define N 1024


typedef struct {
    bool end;
    float array[N];
    unsigned long index;
} SharedMemory;


#define SHM_SIZE sizeof(SharedMemory)


#define SEM_KEY (key_t) 1234
#define SHM_KEY (key_t) 5678

#define READ_SEM 0
#define WRITE_SEM 1


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int shm_id, sem_id;
    void *mem_addr;
    SharedMemory *mem;

    /* Creating the semaphores array (2 semaphores: read and write) */
    sem_id = semget(SEM_KEY, 2, IPC_CREAT | 0666);

    if (sem_id == -1) {
        /* Show the error and exit */
        perror("Error creating the semaphore");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Creating the shared memory */
    shm_id = shmget(SHM_KEY, SHM_SIZE, IPC_CREAT | 0666);

    if (shm_id == -1) {
        /* Show the error and exit */
        perror("Error creating the shared memory");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Attaching the process to shared memory */

    mem_addr = shmat(shm_id, (void *) 0, 0);

    if (mem_addr == (void *) -1) {
        /* Show error and exit() */
        perror("Error attaching memory");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("Memory set to address %X\n", (unsigned) mem_addr);

    mem = (SharedMemory *) mem_addr;

    /* Now the process can start reading the memory */

    while (true) {
        if(SEM_P(sem_id, READ_SEM) == -1) {
            perror("Error");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        if (mem->end == true) {
            break;
        }
        printf("At index %lu of array we have %f\n",
                mem->index, mem->array[mem->index]);
        if (SEM_V(sem_id, WRITE_SEM) == -1) {
            perror("Error");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    /* Detatching memory*/
    if (shmdt(mem_addr) == -1) {
        perror("Error detatching memory");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("Finished.\n");

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

My professor implemented the SystemV semaphore functions as this, thus preventing us from actually use the original APIs:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>


union semun {
    int val;
    struct semid_ds *buf;
    unsigned short *array;
};


int SEM_SET(int sem_id, int sem_num, int sem_val)
{
    union semun sem_union;
    sem_union.val = sem_val;
    if (semctl(sem_id, sem_num, SETVAL, sem_union) == -1) {
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}


void SEM_DEL(int sem_id, int sem_num)
{
    union semun sem_union;
    if (semctl(sem_id, sem_num, SETVAL, sem_union) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to delete the semaphore.\n");
    }
}


int SEM_P(int sem_id, int sem_num)
{
    struct sembuf sem_b;
    sem_b.sem_num = sem_num;
    sem_b.sem_op = -1;
    sem_b.sem_flg = SEM_UNDO;
    if (semop(sem_id, &sem_b, 1) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "P() failed.\n");
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}


int SEM_V(int sem_id, int sem_num)
{
    struct sembuf sem_b;
    sem_b.sem_num = sem_num;
    sem_b.sem_op = 1;
    sem_b.sem_flg = SEM_UNDO;
    if (semop(sem_id, &sem_b, 1) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "V() failed.\n");
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

A sample output from the program is this:

```
./producer 100
Memory set to address EE31000
Failed to delete the semaphore.
Failed to delete the semaphore.
Finished.
```

And

```
./consumer
Memory set to address C63C7000
At index 754 of array we have 4.888889
At index 332 of array we have 12.666667
At index 525 of array we have 86.000000
At index 958 of array we have 32.500000
At index 462 of array we have 13.333333
At index 10 of array we have 18.600000
At index 164 of array we have 9.000000
At index 751 of array we have 5.555555
At index 850 of array we have 1.900000
At index 701 of array we have 3.000000
At index 291 of array we have 12.142858
At index 631 of array we have 20.250000
At index 246 of array we have 9.900000
At index 29 of array we have 9.857142
At index 98 of array we have 9.000000
At index 399 of array we have 30.000000
At index 580 of array we have 2.750000
At index 47 of array we have 1.625000
At index 435 of array we have 1.777778
At index 556 of array we have 1.666667
At index 827 of array we have 5.600000
At index 45 of array we have 7.000000
At index 832 of array we have 28.666666
At index 214 of array we have 13.750000
At index 276 of array we have 5.750000
At index 483 of array we have 6.625000
At index 988 of array we have 8.500000
At index 447 of array we have 0.833333
At index 136 of array we have 23.000000
At index 505 of array we have 9.888889
At index 205 of array we have 3.500000
At index 1014 of array we have 0.166667
At index 193 of array we have 22.500000
At index 315 of array we have 8.000000
At index 291 of array we have 4.500000
At index 582 of array we have 40.000000
At index 176 of array we have 9.777778
At index 259 of array we have 5.166667
At index 560 of array we have 2.875000
At index 905 of array we have 4.000000
At index 972 of array we have 3.000000
At index 27 of array we have 20.000000
At index 750 of array we have 3.000000
At index 315 of array we have 15.000000
At index 800 of array we have 44.000000
At index 255 of array we have 10.000000
At index 104 of array we have 34.000000
At index 926 of array we have 15.000000
At index 721 of array we have 3.750000
At index 948 of array we have 0.666667
At index 117 of array we have 5.600000
At index 77 of array we have 9.500000
At index 875 of array we have 1.000000
At index 271 of array we have 7.500000
At index 527 of array we have 14.500000
At index 896 of array we have 18.666666
At index 836 of array we have 4.888889
At index 313 of array we have 9.111111
At index 796 of array we have 7.500000
At index 375 of array we have 5.000000
At index 579 of array we have 0.100000
At index 588 of array we have 7.142857
At index 393 of array we have 2.750000
At index 187 of array we have 0.500000
At index 287 of array we have 33.000000
At index 982 of array we have 11.125000
At index 808 of array we have 10.500000
At index 965 of array we have 8.857142
At index 687 of array we have 11.750000
At index 536 of array we have 12.500000
At index 393 of array we have 8.714286
At index 206 of array we have 4.900000
At index 2 of array we have 19.000000
At index 531 of array we have 10.000000
At index 61 of array we have 24.500000
At index 415 of array we have 19.666666
At index 826 of array we have 0.800000
At index 374 of array we have 2.428571
At index 1008 of array we have 13.333333
At index 377 of array we have 3.571429
At index 455 of array we have 0.250000
At index 333 of array we have 2.100000
At index 90 of array we have 2.700000
At index 601 of array we have 7.100000
At index 90 of array we have 1.777778
At index 107 of array we have 91.000000
At index 526 of array we have 10.800000
At index 134 of array we have 0.000000
At index 268 of array we have 3.000000
At index 702 of array we have 69.000000
At index 786 of array we have 10.000000
At index 75 of array we have 4.285714
At index 182 of array we have 14.666667
At index 476 of array we have 5.428571
At index 119 of array we have 17.600000
At index 424 of array we have 2.714286
At index 324 of array we have 73.000000
At index 628 of array we have 23.000000
At index 253 of array we have 6.400000
At index 910 of array we have 11.500000
Finished.
```

It seems that everything works, that I'm able to share the memory between the two processes without any issue.
But it seems it fails to delete the semaphores at the end. I tried to interpret the sem_num value as both the single value of that semaphore in the specific array, and as the actual size of the array of semaphores, but both gave me this error. Is there something wrong?